# Duda python (bucle, split y más....)

Tags: python

A ver si me podeis ayudar con este tema comunidad.

Dada una molécula representada por un string del estilo `C9-H8-O4` calcula su masa atómica. Por ejemplo, para una molécula `C4-H3`, la masa atómica sería de `4 * 12.01 + 3 * 1.007825`.

Tengo que hacer una solución general accediendo al diccionario mediante la clave, que en este caso será el tipo de átomo. Por
ejemplo, para la molécula `C5-H3` debería hacer algo asi:

- Separar la molecula por los guiones (*¿con la función `split`?*).
- Para cada una de las partes, `C5` y `H3`, encontrar el tipo de átomo: `C` y `H`. (*¿algún bucle?*)
- Acceder al diccionario de masas y, para la clave que se corresponde con el tipo de átomo, obtener la masa.
- Una vez encontrada la masa, multiplicarla por el número de átomos encontrados.

Tengo esto escrito:

## Masas atómicas

```
masas = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071,
'P': 30.973762}

def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    """
    Calcula la masa atomica de una molecula
    """
    masa = 0.0
return masa
```

## Código a completar

```
print calcula_masa_atomica('C13-H18-O2')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C8-H10-N4-O2')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C20-H25-N3-O')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C20-H10-O2-P2-S')
```

Comment: Si, la funcion `split` es la adecuada. Para encontrar el tipo de átomo yo cogeria el segundo caracter (previamente asegurate que `Length>1`) y comprobaria: si es un numero(`isNumeric`), coges el primer caracter (`string[:1]`) para buscarlo en el diccionario (buena idea para estructura de datos), si no es un numero coges los dos primeros caracteres(`string[:2]`) .

Comment: @lois6b, fíjate en los ejemplos. Hay algunos casos donde aparecen letras sin números.

Comment: @ChemaCortes ya , por eso digo que compruebe la longitud del `string` tras el `split`

Comment: Tu pregunta ha tenido varias respuestas, que deberían servirte. No entiendo qué es eso de *"no querer hacer otro script"*. Estamos aquí para ayudarte, no para hacer tu trabajo. Si no sabes cómo encajar la respuesta en lo que necesitas, pregunta con aquellas dudas que aún tengas o que no hayas entendido. Pero **nunca** pidas te demos el código limpio y pulido para copiar sin hacer el mínimo esfuerzo por tu parte.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la mejor opción es usar *expresiones regulares*. Te pongo un código de ejemplo:

```
import re

# Grupos de varias letras, seguidas (o no) de números
pat = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)(\d*)")  
masas = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071, 
'P': 30.973762}

def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    grupos = [(atom, int(n) if n else 1) 
                 for (atom, n) in pat.findall(molecula)]

    masa = sum(n*masas.get(atom,0.0) for (atom,n) in grupos)
    return masa
```

Si hubiera algún símbolo en la fórmula de masa desconocida, se toma `0.0` como peso atómico. Puede ser mejor que dé una excepción.

Comment: Mi respuesta era igual (solo que en mi caso `grupos`es un generador y no una lista) pero has publicado antes la respuesta... XD. Para mi esta es la mejor forma de hacerlo (usando expresiones regulares) ya que permite calcular las masas de moleculas cuyos atomos tienen dos caracteres como el caso del saludable **bicloruro de mercurio** `Hg-Cl2`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, lo estudiare pero en principio parece todo muy logico

Comment: Tengo que hacerlo completando este script. Como podria?masas = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071,
'P': 30.973762}

def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    """
    Calcula la masa atomica de una molecula
    """
    masa = 0.0
return masa
Código a completar

print calcula_masa_atomica('C13-H18-O2')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C8-H10-N4-O2')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C20-H25-N3-O')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C20-H10-O2-P2-S')

Answer (score 1):

Algo que se me ocurrio rapido fue esto:

```
masas = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071, 
'P': 30.973762}

moleculas = "H4-C2"

print [{i: float(masas.get(i[0])) * float(i[1:])}  
        if i[1:] else {i: float(masas.get(i[0]))} 
        for i in moleculas.split('-')]
```

Espero que te ayude.

Saludos

Comment: Por supuesto que ayuda, compartir conocimiento es fantastico.

Comment: Lo que tengo que hacer es completar el Script que pongo arriba que es este  masas = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071,
'P': 30.973762}

def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    """
    Calcula la masa atomica de una molecula
    """
    masa = 0.0
return masa
Código a completar

print calcula_masa_atomica('C13-H18-O2')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C8-H10-N4-O2')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C20-H25-N3-O')
print calcula_masa_atomica('C20-H10-O2-P2-S')